# dynamically allocating vector containing vector to be allocated dynamically

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm learning C++ and when practicing on Hackerrank, I encountered vectors containing vectors for the first time. [This](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem) is the problem to solve.
From the program provided below, I want to know:

1. Is it the correct way to declare the required vector as I did?
2. Does the statement "a.resize(i)" at line 27 work as I intend it to?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<array>
bool inrange(int min, int max, int x)
{
    //check if x is in range
    return (x >= min && x <= max);
}

int main(void)
{
    int q{}, n{}; //for no. of queries & no. of elements in array
    std::cin >> q >> n;
    if (inrange(1, 100000, q)) //ensure q to be in specified range
    {
        if (inrange(1, 100000, n))
        {
            //for declaring vector of vectors
            using innertype = std::vector<int>;
            std::vector <innertype> a;
            //array to store no. of elements in each ith array
            std::vector <int> ki;

            for (int i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i)
            {
                //extend vector by one element
>line 27                a.resize(i);
                //get the array for ith position
                int j{ 0 }; char buffer;
                do
                {
                    //extend vector at ith index by one element
                    a[i].resize(j);
                    std::cin >> a[i][j];
                    std::cin >> buffer;
                    ++j;
                } while (buffer != '\n');
                ki.resize(j);
                ki[i] = j;
            }
            //take indexes for query1 and query2 to print requested elements
            int i{}, j{};
            std::cin >> i >> j;
            std::array q1request{ i,j };
            std::cin >> i >> j;
            std::array q2request{ i,j };
            //print elements "a[i][j]"
            std::cout << a[q1request[i]][q1request[j]] << '\n';
            std::cout << a[q1request[i]][q2request[j]];

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program terminates after taking two inputs.

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Expression: vector subscript out of range

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing really wrong with your usage of `vector` apart from indexing (maybe a bit strange, but not wrong). The usage of the resize method of the `vector` is missused. For the pre-allocation of the vector, two methods are used in general. `resize()` and `reserve()`.

One can be used in case you need indexing the `vector`.

```
std::vector<int> test(10, 0); // creating vector of 10 items set to 0
test.resize(100); // resizing to allocate space for 100 elements
// test.size() == 100
for(size_t i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i)
{
 test[i] = i;
 std::cout << "Filling " << i << "th element." << std::endl;
}
```

The other  is used usually when you dont need the index.

```
std::vector<int> test;
test.reserve(100); // reserve space for at least 100 elements
// test.size() == 0
for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
 test.push_back(i); // will not allocate new memory
}
```

The issue you have is that you resize the vector to hold 0 elements in 1st iteration and then you access element at index 0. The same would go for any other subsequent index.

Comment: Got it. But I need some clarification on why you preferred to use "size_t" in place of "int" as it would help me know a bit more.

Comment: In first case it is used to avoid warnings with type conversions - `size()` method returns value of type `size_t`. In the second example it is just a copy paste. `size_t` is just a using for `unsigned long long`. Generally you want to use at least `unsigned` data type for indexing, although there are some exceptions.

Comment: After making changes ("a.resize(i+1)"), what I find by watching 'buffer' through watch window, is that it asks for another input from the user. But I expected it to get the 'whitespace' character previously left in std::cin buffer, after inputting the integer. What am I missing?

Comment: You should really put the `resize()` of the vector out of the loop (resize it to n). The second issue is really a case for debugging and stepping throught the code.